# Transfer excel userform form data to work sheets selected in combobox

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I've been using excel UF technic for 8 months.
I am working in very small company and preparing stock inventory management in excel user form. (user form image attached for ref)

We have 3 stores wiz...

1. Main store
2. KanBan store &
3. Shopfloor.

Initially the new material will always get entered to main stores.
upon material withdraw using MIR document - the material will be stored in our production KanBan system.

Later it will be taken into shop floor based on daily requirement.
My idea is to create userform to enter material at any gate and while withdrawing I will also choose the location it is getting transferred.
At backend - in excel worksheet I will use formula to calculate diff between inward & outward to calculate stock volume for any given store location.

How to implement one gate in vba? I will use same for other gates.

Eg. I will have worksheets separately for new stock input (+) and another worksheet to enter withdraw qty (-) , using formula in 3 sheet, I will see the dif of each line item & will update as balance qty in main store. while updating withdraw sheet, same values will get update to Kanban(+) sheet, as material inward to Kanban store. like this on excel I will shift the component location store by store.

[image]

[image: image 1]

[image]

Comment: Sorry pals, as I was trying to add supporting image of my user form, I realized that, I am not able to select all 3 images at once or load all 3 image one after the another. any point of time, it is only allowing me to have one image , please replay me with your clarification so that I can post relevant images again

Comment: It is very unclear what your question is because you didn't ask one. Also your post looks very complex, please try to reduce it to your actual issue and to the relevant part. Read [mcve] and try to build an example of your issue (showing the code you have tried) so we can reproduce it. Reading [ask] might also help to improve your question. This post is too broad to answer I think.

Comment: If you're just looking for adding data to a sheet whose name is defined by a userform combobox (looking purely at your post title), you can define your location such that:   *Sheets(Userform1.ComboBox12.Value).Cells(LR+1,2).Value = ""*, where I have assumed you are finding the last row in the required sheet and pasting +1 row in column 2